# Java Console JPanel

Tags: java, swing, console, jpanel

Hello
Is it possible to draw in a JPanel what the java console is returning ?
have you got a tutorial to follow ?
thanks
sw

Comment: You may wish to add "Swing" to your question's tags to attract the forum Swing experts.  :)

Answer (score 7):

I can't remember where I found this, but I have outputted the output stream to a JTextArea held in a JPanel using a class I call TextAreaOutputStream:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TextAreaOutputStream extends OutputStream {

    private final JTextArea textArea;
    private final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    private String title;

    public TextAreaOutputStream(final JTextArea textArea, String title) {
        this.textArea = textArea;
        this.title = title;
        sb.append(title + "> ");
    }

    @Override
    public void flush() {
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
    }

    @Override
    public void write(int b) throws IOException {

        if (b == '\r')
            return;

        if (b == '\n') {
            final String text = sb.toString() + "\n";
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    textArea.append(text);
                }
            });
            sb.setLength(0);
            sb.append(title).append("> ");
        }

        sb.append((char) b);
    }
}
```

I then re-direct the standard output Stream to this object as Alex mentions in his answer above.

Comment: `sb.append(title).append("> ");` would probably be more efficient.

Comment: @DavidConrad: indeed it would as it would avoid a String concat. Thanks, and answer edited.

Answer (score 2):

First read from the console. To do this use System.setOut(). Use ByteOutputStream, write there and read from their. You will get what your program prints to it system out. Now use either TextArea or JScrollPane to present the text.

Answer (score 2):

Create a subclass of FilterOutputStream to echo everything to a JTextArea.

```
class Echo extends FilterOutputStream {

    private final JTextArea text;

    public Echo(OutputStream out, JTextArea text) {
        super(out);
        if (text == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("null text");
        this.text = text;
    }

    @Override
    public void write(int b) throws IOException {
        super.write(b);
        text.append(Character.toString((char) b));
        // scroll to end?
    }

    // overwrite the other write methods for better performance
}
```

and replace the standard output:

```
    JTextArea text = new JTextArea();
    System.setOut(new PrintStream(new Echo(System.out, text)));
```

Answer (score 2):

The [Message Console](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/08/message-console/) provides a few more options that might interest you.