# Command Line Jar on Android Device

Tags: android, jar, command-line-interface

I currently have a compiled jar file that I would like to use on an android device. The code outputs to the command line using System.out.println().

How would I create a wrapper to grab the stdout and put it in a text view on an android device? Would I need to make any changes to the jar (I do have all the source code) to allow the wrapper?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need to make some changes. You can set standart output by calling

```
System.setOut(PrintStream out) 
// Reassigns the "standard" output stream.
```

Where `out` is your own class that will print data to text view. See [swing solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4422642/java-console-jpanel). Just set appending to text view and you can use this code.

Or just create one method

```
void log(String message);
```

where you appending text to your view. Then change all `println()` calls to this.

Answer (score 0):

First you should consider that Android has a specific Java VM called Dalvik and not any jar can be ran under it.

- If there's one point in your jar where output occurs, the best option would be to create a usual application with a `TextView`, include your jar to it's build path and replace a call to `println()` with output to it:

  ```
  public void print(String msg) {
      mTextView.setText(msg);
  }
  ```
- If there're many sources of output you could run you jar using `java.lang.Process` and use it's `getInputStream()` method to read printed messages:

  ```
  public static final String XBOOT_CLASS_PATH = "-Xbootclasspath:/system/framework/core.jar"
  public static final String CLASS_PATH = "-classpath /path/to/your/file.jar com.your.package.name"
  ...
  Process p = new ProcessBuilder("dalvikvm", XBOOT_CLASS_PATH, CLASS_PATH).start();
  BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
  String msg = reader.readLine();
  if (msg != null) {
      mTextView.setText(msg);
  }
  // Cleanup omitted for simplicity
  ```

Comment: In fact @alaster solution is far more elegant

Answer (score 0):

If it's an executable jar file here is a working example

Add this simple executable HelloWorld [jar file](http://csdl.ics.hawaii.edu/~johnson/613f99/modules/04/psae.jar) to your Android Project's build path

If the jar file doesn't have a package, then you will have to use `Reflection` to invoke methods in it.Other wise you can just import the class files and invoke the main method directly.(This example jar has a package "psae")

eg:

```
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textv);
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(baos);
System.setOut(ps);
String[] params = {"Aneesh","Joseph"};
psae.HelloWorld.main(params);
String output = baos.toString();
tv.setText(output)
```

If the jar file just has a default package, then you won't be able to import class files from that jar, and hence you will have to use `Reflection` to invoke the method.

```
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textv);
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(baos);
System.setOut(ps);
try {
    //pick the entry class from the jar Manifest
    //Main-Class: psae.HelloWorld
    Class myClass = Class.forName("psae.HelloWorld");
    //since this has a package, there is no need of reflection.This is just an example
    //If the jar file had just a default package, the it would have been something like the below line (and this is where it would be useful) 
    //Class myClass = Class.forName("Main");
    Method myMethod = myClass.getMethod("main", String[].class);
    //parameters to the main method
    String[] params = {"Aneesh","Joseph"};
    myMethod.invoke(null, (Object) params);  
    String output = baos.toString();
    tv.setText(output);
 }
catch(Exception d)
 {
     tv.setText(d.toString());  
 }
```